# Looking for pi until percent error is below 1e-2

Tags: python, loops, pi

I'm using [this formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2FpV.png) that involves factorials and double factorials to find value of pi until percent error is below 1e-2. For some reason the while loop that's calculating pi until that PE is low enough doesn't stop (at least that's what I think is happening).

```py
import numpy as np

k = 1
pe = 100


def doublefactorial(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    return n * doublefactorial(n - 2)


while pe >= 1e-2:
    f = 1
    for i in range(1, k + 1):
        f = f * i
    D = doublefactorial(2 * k + 1)
    r = f / D
    pe = abs(((r - np.pi) / np.pi) * 100)
    k = k + 1

print("pi= ", r, "PE= ", pe)
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of things that could be improved in your code, below is a commented version with said improvements:

1. That for you are using to calculate `k!` was hard to understand, so I used python's factorial function and changed your `f/D` to `N/D`, keeping the fraction form you used.
2. This is a summation, so don't forget to update `r`'s value every iteration.
3. The output of the formula is Pi / 2, so you can't compare it directly with `np.pi`.
4. You start with `k=1`, but your formula states `k=0`.

Also I moved the print inside the loop so you can see the values updating on each iteration.

```py
import numpy as np
import math

k = 0
r = 0
pe = 100


def doublefactorial(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    return n * doublefactorial(n - 2)


while pe >= 1e-2:
    # using math.factorial for easier to read code
    N = math.factorial(k)
    D = doublefactorial(2 * k + 1)
    # our approximation = numerator / dividend
    # update r's value (this is equivalent to r = r + N/D)
    r += N / D

    # don't forget the formula gives Pi/2 so to compare and print we should double it...
    pi_approx = 2 * r
    pe = abs(((pi_approx - np.pi) / np.pi) * 100)
    k = k + 1
    print("pi= ", pi_approx, "PE= ", pe)
```